# Reactive Mono API multi parameters request handler

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I am new to Reactive Programming and I am struggling to do something simple.
I have router that executes GET requests and I handled a request with one param like this:

http://localhost:8080/creditCardPay?amount=100

handler:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> creditCardPay(ServerRequest request) {
    Optional<String> amountParam = request.queryParam("amount");
    Mono<String> result = Mono.just(amountParam.get())
            .map(x -> restapi.dosometing(x,something));
    return ServerResponse.ok().body(result,String.class);
}
```

I want to be able handel multi params but the Mono.just i wrote could handle only one.
How do I handle multi params?

Comment: I am not asking how to do multi params GET request , but how I can handle one with Mono.just() ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the RESTful api syntax

{amount:int}/MethodName/{amount2:int}"

http://localhost:8080/creditCardPay/100/nextVariableName(plural nouns)/200

(check this [link](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) for the full RESTapi standards)

also you can go for other a 3rd party api standards like this [one](https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards)

or you can use QueryString but it won't keep your code clean if there are many params,

http://localhost:8080/creditCardPay?amount=100&amount2=200

Comment: you could also turn your api to type "post" so you can send a body with the request that have all the params names and values , but this way is not recommended